# C# variable formulation in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, variables, formula

I want to select my formulation by a checkbox before a loop. Because if i select formulation in loop, code works very slow. So i should make the formulation variable. Here is a sample code below. How can i do this?

```
            formula1 = 2 * a + b;
            formula2 = 4 * a + 2 * c;
            formula3= 2 * c + 12 * b + a;

            if (checkBox1.Checked==true)
            {formula_select=formula1}
            if (checkBox2.Checked==true)
            {formula_select=formula2}
            if (checkBox3.Checked==true)
            {formula_select=formula3}

            for (int i = 1; i < 500000; i++)
        {
                a=a+1;
                b=5
                c=2;
                formula_select   //for example; formula 2 should be calculated here
                formula_select* some_numbers; // answer of formula2 should be used here
                other calculations
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us code that will compile? I also don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you trying to choose a function to run on the numbers based on the checkboxes?

Comment: its unclear what you are asking for

Comment: These formulas and numbers are just simple example. Actual formulas are very long and there are a lot of calculations. I want to do the formula selection before loop.

Comment: Side note (also known as rambling ;) ): You should rather use RadioButtons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: I am using tabcontrols instead of checkboxes. This is just an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To choose the formula to execute you can use a delegate. Example:

```
Func<int, int, int, int> formula_select;

if (checkBox1.Checked) {
  formula_select = (a, b, c) => 2 * a + b;
} else if (checkBox2.Checked) {
  formula_select = (a, b, c) => 4 * a + 2 * c;
} else if (checkBox3.Checked) {
  formula_select = (a, b, c) => 2 * c + 12 * b + a;
}

for (int i = 1; i < 500000; i++) {
  a=a+1;
  b=5
  c=2;
  int x = formula_select(a, b, c);
  int y = x * some_numbers;
}
```

However, as there is some overhead in the function call, it might not make it faster. It's not sure that it's actually that part of the code that is slow. You should try to simply store the state from the checkbox controls in variables and use in the loop, that might be where the actual bottle neck is:

```
bool check1 = checkBox1.Checked;
bool check2 = checkBox2.Checked;
bool check3 = checkBox3.Checked;

for (int i = 1; i < 500000; i++) {
  a=a+1;
  b=5
  c=2;

  int x;
  if (check1) {
    x = 2 * a + b;
  } else if (check2) {
    x = 4 * a + 2 * c;
  } else if (check3) {
    x = 2 * c + 12 * b + a;
  }

  int y = x * some_numbers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works faster than 3 different if control. Are there any things that can make code faster? Because if i use only one formula (closing other formula choices) it works faster.

Comment: You could try making a single integer value from the checkboxes, i.e. `int formula = check1 ? 1 : check2 ? 2 : 3;`, then use it in a `switch` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks again. I searched about switch and used it. It is working faster now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre compiled lambda expressions using expression trees to make it faster

**Code Snippet:**

Expression> formula1 = (x, y, z) => 2 * x + y;

```
        Expression<Func<int, int, int, int>> formula2 = (x, y, z) => 4 * x + 2 * z;
        Expression<Func<int, int, int, int>> formula3 = (x, y, z) => 2 * z + 12 * y + x;


        Func<int, int, int, int> formula_select=null;
         if (this.formula1.IsChecked.HasValue &&this.formula1.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            formula_select = formula1.Compile(); 
        }
        else if (this.formula2.IsChecked.HasValue&&this.formula2.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            formula_select = formula2.Compile();
        }
        else if (this.formula3.IsChecked.HasValue&&this.formula3.IsChecked.Value)
        {
            formula_select = formula3.Compile(); 
        }
        int a=0, b, c,someNumber=1;
        for (int i = 1; i < 500000; i++)
    {
            a=a+1;
            b=5;
            c=2;
            int result=formula_select(a,b,c);
            int someResult = result * someNumber;

    }
```